# dplyr return ALL columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I just started using `dplyr` and `tidyr` and have a question:

I have data frame with columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. I want to mutate all values in columns `B` and `C` **in place** or return all columns after selecting `B` and `C`. Eg.

```r
data <- data %>%
    dplyr::select(select=B:C) %>%
    dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, stringr::str_replace_all,
        pattern = "x", replacement = "y")
```

I want `data` to include **ALL** columns in the end and the `select` command only to affect the following operations and not actually subset the data frame. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points:

- you can call the library once instead of using `dplyr::` each time.
- I'm not sure if you need that `is.character` since you just asked to apply your function to B and C
- I suggest you to use `across` which has superseded the use of `mutate_if` [starting from dplyr >= 1.0.0]

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
    mutate(across(c(B,C), stringr::str_replace_all,
           pattern = "x", replacement = "y"))
```

Comment: thank you for this incredibly quick response. Can across() also give a range of columns? E.g. across(B:F) for columns B to F?

Comment: yes. just replace `c(B,C)` with `B:C`. Or `B:F`, whatever you need.

Comment: nice. works perfectly! much better than what I used to do!